# Grails controller populated menu with separate main controller view

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-controller

I am trying to create a membership directory.  I have the directory filled out and ready to go. I am using the main.gsp layout and have created the templates for it.

The side navigation bar needs to be populated by the committees and boards that the members belong too.  I have created that through a separate domain and controller.  The view that it creates makes links that pass search parameters by the committee.id to the member page to sort the list of members.

I am trying to populate that side navigation bar with the committee control throughout the layout of the site but when I got to test out the site that template section does not populate.  It just populates when the committee controller page is selected that I created to test my output.  I believe that I am missing a call to the controller or some reference that makes this view active throughout the site and not just on the controller page.

I am using Grails v. 2.3.3

Here is the code for the side navigation bar in main.gsp.

```
<div id="leftNav" >
    <g:render template="/common/left_nav" model="[hospital:Hospital]" />
</div>
```

Here is where the navigation template is called in "_left_nav.gsp".

```
<div>
    <g:render template="/hospital/committee" model="[hospital:Hospital]" />
</div>
```

Here is where the navigation template is called again in "_committee.gsp".

```
<%@ page import="trustees.Hospital" %>

<div id="hospcomm" class="content scaffold-list" role="navigation">
    <table>
        <g:each in="${hospitalInstanceList}" status="i" var="hospitalInstance">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <g:link controller="hospital" action="show" id="${hospitalInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: hospitalInstance, field: "hospitalName")}</g:link>

<%--            <g:link action="show" id="${hospitalInstance.id}">--%>
<%--                <a href="index.jsp?nav=main&hosp=<%=hospGiven %>" target="_top">--%>
<%--                    <img src="/Trustees/static/images/img/navigate.msh_board.gif" border="0">--%>
<%--                </a>--%>
<%--            </g:link>    --%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <g:each in="${hospitalInstance.committees}">
                    <li>
                        <g:link controller="hospital" action="show" id="${it.id}">  ${it.committeeName} </g:link>
                    </li>
                    </g:each>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </g:each>
    </table>
</div>
```

The controller for this view is being called dynamically.

Comment: You are expecting a `hospitalInstanceList` in your template but you are calling it with a `hospital` object. You probably need to call your template with a list no?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The side navigation bar would only be populated when you access that particular controller's action. You have 2 options, compute this value in every controller's action that would use a view with the side navigation bar or use a filter

If you want this info on every page, I would recommend you trying to make this accessible by using a Filter. You can retrieve ***hospital*** everytime a page is loaded.

If you are using a Security plugin, such as Shiro or SpringSecurity as part of your app, you could place this bit there.